# Receive white screen when adding guards to bjyauthorize

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2, zend-db, bjyauthorize

I'm new to ZF2 and bjyauthorize - so in a way hoping this is a silly mistake on my part :D

I have setup the ZF2 skeleton app and zfcUser successfully and am trying to add bjyAuthorize to the mix. I am also using the Zend/Db connection type to mySQL - NOT DOCTRINE (:D). The versions I am using are PHP(5.5), ZF2(2.3.*), zfcUser(1.2.1), bjyAuthorize(1.4.0).

I have followed the instructions found to the letter in the [GitHub Readme](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize).  It didn't take me long to realise that the example "***bjyauthorize.global.php***" file there contains way too many settings (as examples) and also has an incorrect field reference under "***\BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\ZendDb::class***" ("role_id" s/b "roleid").

Basically, as soon as I uncomment either the route based or controller based guards in my config file (i don't intend to do both - just want one working) I get a white screen - no error message to be helpful - when trying to access my skeleton apps home page. I'm worried this is therefore a PHP syntax error on my part.

I have also included ZendDeveloperTools and not even the tool bar on the footer appears when I get this error.

Here is my config file:

```
<?php

return [
    'bjyauthorize' => [

        // set the 'guest' role as default (must be defined in a role provider)
        'default_role' => 'guest',

        /* this module uses a meta-role that inherits from any roles that should
         * be applied to the active user. the identity provider tells us which
         * roles the "identity role" should inherit from.
         *
         * for ZfcUser, this will be your default identity provider
         */
        'identity_provider' => \BjyAuthorize\Provider\Identity\ZfcUserZendDb::class,

        /* role providers simply provide a list of roles that should be inserted
         * into the Zend\Acl instance. the module comes with two providers, one
         * to specify roles in a config file and one to load roles using a
         * Zend\Db adapter.
         */
        'role_providers' => [
            // this will load roles from the user_role table in a database
            // format: user_role(role_id(varchar], parent(varchar))
            \BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\ZendDb::class => [
                'table'                 => 'user_role',
                'identifier_field_name' => 'id',
                'role_id_field'         => 'roleid',
                'parent_role_field'     => 'parent_id',
            ],
        ],

        /* Currently, only controller and route guards exist
         *
         * Consider enabling either the controller or the route guard depending on your needs.
         */
        'guards' => [
            /* If this guard is specified here (i.e. it is enabled], it will block
             * access to all controllers and actions unless they are specified here.
             * You may omit the 'action' index to allow access to the entire controller
             */
//             \BjyAuthorize\Guard\Controller::class => [
//                 ['controller' => 'zfcuser', 'roles' => ['guest']],
//                 ['controller' => ['Application\Controller\Index'], 'roles' => ['guest']],
//             ],

//             /* If this guard is specified here (i.e. it is enabled], it will block
//              * access to all routes unless they are specified here.
//              */
//             \BjyAuthorize\Guard\Route::class => [
//                 ['route' => 'zfcuser', 'roles' => ['user']],
//                 ['route' => 'zfcuser/logout', 'roles' => ['user']],
//                 ['route' => 'zfcuser/login', 'roles' => ['guest']],
//                 ['route' => 'zfcuser/register', 'roles' => ['guest']],
//                 // Below is the default index action used by the ZendSkeletonApplication
//                 ['route' => 'home', 'roles' => ['guest', 'user']],
//             ],
         ],
    ],
];
```

When I run as coded above without guards, I can login through site/user/login and the Zend Dev ToolBar shows me the correct role for that user. So that is at least positive.

Happy to provide any further info or settings - just trying to learn.

Comment: After "playing" around with the settings, I have found that if I replace the code:

    \BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\ZendDb::class => [
        'table' => 'user_role',
        'identifier_field_name' => 'id',
        'role_id_field' => 'roleid',
        'parent_role_field' => 'parent_id',
     ],

with:

    \BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\Config::class => [
        'guest' => [],
        'user'  => ['children' => [
            'admin' => [],
         ]],
    ],

It works fine - so the question then becomes why is it failing to get the roles from the DB ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I feel quite silly now.

The DB schema that bjyauthorize ships with has the field "**roleId**" - in my code above I didn't take into account case sensitivity and had "**roleid**".  Changed that and everything works perfectly.